# why Every Thread need to execute Selector.select In netty

Tags: java, netty, nio

when I read **Netty-4.0.0.Final.jar's** source code,I found the following puzzling code in NioEventLoop.java:

```
protected void run() {
    for (;;) {
        oldWakenUp = wakenUp.getAndSet(false);
        try {
            if (hasTasks()) {
                selectNow();
            } else {
                select();
                if (wakenUp.get()) {
                    selector.wakeup();
                }
            }
            //ignore some code
            processSelectedKeysPlain(selector.selectedKeys());
            //ignore some code
    }
}
```

In traditional network program, use one dedicated thread to receive ready event(accept connection, read, write) and use a pool of threads to provide service.

i get the point.

netty also follow this pattern.
using

```
ServerBootstrap.group(EventLoopGroup parentGroup, EventLoopGroup childGroup)
```

not

```
ServerBootstrap.group(EventLoopGroup group)
```

thanks for reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In traditional network program, use one dedicated thread to accept
>   connection and use a pool of threads to provide service.

That is because the accept connection part is Blocking it needs to be done in one thread so that connections can be made with server and connection processing (reading, writing as well) must be delegated to different threads to keep things running.

> why netty choose to mix the task of accepting and providing service In
>   every Thread?

This is because it uses `select` from `java.nio` (Non Blocking I/O) package. Select has been around since C/C++ and it allows Synchronous I/O Multiplexing. In short it allows to monitor multiple sockets and check whether those sockets are reading, writing or have exceptions.

Because of `select`'s Non Blocking nature it can be used to check for connections as well as process those connections in a Single Thread.

Comment: I don't see anything in the above mentioned code that shows that Netty is "accepting" connections in that thread.  Can you point it out for me?